# How to compare or check and matched ids are removed. return remaining values in an array how?

Tags: php

```
function RemoveLightOk($onlist) {
    $remainingvalues= array();
    $remainingvalues= explode('' , $onlist);
    foreach ($remainingvalues as $key){ 

        $query = mysql_query("select * from table where id = '".$key."'");
        $rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $id = $rs["id"];
                // How to compare or check and matched ids are removed. return remaining values in an array how? 

    }
    return $remainingvalues;
}
```

Here is `$onlist` means this is one array. Like all ids are together into array. Using PHP only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following line has a typo as it has no meaning:

```
$remainingvalues= explode('' , $onlist);
```

Assuming this was meant: (values are separated by space)

```
$remainingvalues= explode(' ', $onlist);
```

First remove any nonnumeric value from list to prevent Sql Injection:

```
$filtered = array_filter($remainingvalues, 'is_numeric');
```

Then you can fetch all existing values with a single query

```
 $query = mysql_query("select id from table where id IN (". implode(',', $filtered) . ")";
```

Then you can create another array with existing values:

```
$existing = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $existing[] = $row['id'];
}
```

Then return diff of these two arrays:

```
return array_diff($filtered, $existing)
```

Comment: I am using this array_diff() function. But i have the problem. array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array.  How to solve this issue..

Comment: Argument#1 of array_diff is $filtered right? Do you modify it after it is initialized with array_filter? (btw I edited my answer for a minor correction in query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ;

```
function RemoveLightOk($onlist) {
    $remainingvalues= array();
    foreach ($onlist as $k => $v){ 

        $query = mysql_query("select * from table where id = '".$v."'");
        $rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if (!empty($rs["id"]) {
            $remainingvalues[] = $v;
        } 

    }
    return $remainingvalues;
}
```

**Warning:** I suggest you not to use `mysql_query`. This is from php doc page;

`This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:`